# Not working below angularjs code

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="myTrack in myTrackList">
<td class="project-status" data-ng-switch="myTrack.opened">
                                        <span  data-ng-switch-when="true" class="label label-primary">Active</span>
                                        <span data-ng-switch-when="false" class="label label-default">Inactive</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="project-title"><a
                                        id="{{myTrack.trackId}},{{myTrack.file.fileId}}"
                                        href="getDocumentByFileId?fileId={{myTrack.file.fileId}}&trackId={{myTrack.trackId}}">{{myTrack.trackName}}</a>
                                        <br /><small>Description: {{myTrack.description}}</small>
                                        <br /> <small>Created: {{myTrack.createdTime}}</small></td>
                                    <td class="project-people" colspan="2">
                                        <div class="project-people" ng-repeat="persons in myTrack.personTrack">                                         
                                            <a href=""><img alt="image" title="persons.firstName"
                                                class="img-circle" src="persons.profilePictureUrl"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="project-actions"><a href="#"
                                        class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                            View </a></td>
                                </tr>
```

I taken list of objects and in single object there is set of user with their profile picture. I used ng-repeat in ng-repeat for repeating users set from list of objects but my inner ng-repeat not working correctly. please help me.

Comment: can you please add a plunker

Comment: i want to retrieve set from list of objects in angularjs. and i am not able to add plunker because i am using hibernate also for fetching users from database

Comment: does my answer form bellow helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the code bellow :

```
 <div class="project-people" ng-repeat="persons in myTrack.personTrack">                                         
       <a href=""><img alt="image" title="persons.firstName" class="img-circle" src="persons.profilePictureUrl"></a>
    </div>
```

The browser do not know that you are using angular js variable for title or src. So you will need.

```
<div class="project-people" ng-repeat="persons in myTrack.personTrack">                                         
           <a href=""><img alt="image" ng-attr-title="{{persons.firstName}}" class="img-circle" ng-src="{{persons.profilePictureUrl}}"></a>
        </div>
```

So you will need to include the ng tags when you want to use the angular js for tags.